# Newly created AWS member account is missing IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I just created a new account in my organization and I provided a custom IAM role.
The problem is that I can't find the role in IAM, I remember then name and in any case there are few roles there so I can check.
I double checked in cloud trail the IAM role name, and I search for it in IAM and I still can't find it.
Is there something I'm missing or some workaround?

**Background:**
According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/faqs/):

> How can I access an AWS account that was created in my organization?
>
> As part of AWS account creation, AWS Organizations creates an IAM role
> with full administrative permissions in the new account. IAM users and
> IAM roles with appropriate permissions in the master account can
> assume this IAM role to gain access to the newly created account.

**Update:**

The steps of the link below also helped me understand the issue
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: It probably didn't get created. Just create another one. If it complains that the name is already in use, then go hunting for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation, the role is created in the New account. You can `assumeRole` by `sts` service to the role from the master account, so this is the reason you cannot find the role in your account.

You first `assumeRole` and then you can do the administrative job for the new account. You can log in through this link with your role and account.

```
https://signin.aws.amazon.com/switchrole?roleName=<roleName>&account=<newAccountId>
```

Be aware that you should be logged in to your master account first. Replace `<roleName>` and 12-digits `<newAccountId>` for yours.

Comment: Hi, which IAM user are you referring? As a root I created an account in the organization providing the name of the IAM role. Not sure where to look besides IAM Roles.

Comment: Ah, The organization! What you mean the account is AWS account and the role might be in that account not the master account I think.

Comment: I added some related documentation to the question. I need this Role in order to login to the member account.

Comment: Yeap, the role is created in the new account and you should assume the role.

Comment: Yes. that's what the documentation says. I completely missed it.